# Using RNN's with multiple input features

Tags: r, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I was wondering, if I could use Recurrent Neural Networks to do some time series regression with additional features. 
As an example I want to predict stock prices for different companies. I've got historical stock prices as well as additional features to each company like revenue, RoI, RoE, sell out volume etc. Some of them are constant over time (i.e. number of Managers employed) and some are changing over time (i.e. revenue).

I would like to do a forecast for known companies, as well as for new companies without historical stock prices.

I was thinking about using the [RNN Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnn/rnn.pdf) in R. But I cant figure out if it's even possible to use multiple input features for RNN's and if so I don't know how I have to structure the arrays X and Y using the method "trainr".

Comment: Couldn't you just add the constant data as another time-series with constant value?

Comment: So i just use every attribute as a new time series? This would result in several sequences with i.e. 10 time-series and 1 _"result-series"_?

Comment: Something like that yes, you could try that

Comment: You can add constant inputs in at the end and connect them directly to your output neurons.